# Android studio application crash when i add firestore

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want use firebase in my app.
In my app I only use firebaseauth (without problems) but now i want use FirebaseFirestore  (currently I don't have this in  code yet) but when i add 
`implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.6.0'` 
in gradle my app start without errors and then crashes.
Where can i find the problem?

```
                                FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                                DocumentReference df=fStore.collection("users").document(user.getUid());
                                Map<String,Object> userInfo= new HashMap<>();
                                userInfo.put("Email",mail);
                                userInfo.put("Name",name);
                                userInfo.put("Surname",surname);
                                userInfo.put("Phone",phone);
                                userInfo.put("Role","0");//0-user 1-admin 2- courier

                                df.set(userInfo);
```

build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.6.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the crash log please?

Comment: I added in question. image: https://ibb.co/Bzv0bb0

Comment: There's not enough information here.  Your question show the [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that anyone can use to observe the same thing.  If all you've done is add a dependency, then edit the question to show your build.gradle.  If you added code, show that too.

Comment: I added some info, code and link to github. Registration and login works and connects to the database but when i add in build.gradle implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.6.0' app crash

Comment: When i comment implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5' and everything related to this, the application doesn't crash. Have you any idea why ?

Comment: i changed implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5' on 19.4.0 and app work, but why my  application didn't create a collection in the database? codi in question

Comment: On Stack Overflow, if you want to reply to someone, you should use @ with their name to notify them. For example: @WayOver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Firebase library versions don't match - Firebase Auth is too old compared to Firestore.  If you add any library, you have to also have to make sure that all the other versions of the libraries are compatible with it.  It's easiest to simply use the latest versions of everything that you see in the [release notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android).  Minimally, you should upgrade firebase-auth to 19.4.0.

```
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.6.0'
```

Comment: Last question. Android studio added this implementation automatically when I added login in code. Why has android not added the latest version?

Comment: I don't know.  If you have a new question, post it separately.